# Overlay text over my overlay

Tags: css, overlay

I have a overlay problem. I would like to show a text if my overlay is on. If the user clicks then the overlay should go off and the body content should be seen.

But how can I make a text or a picture over the overlay?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            #overlay {
                position: fixed;
                display: none;
                -webkit-filter:blur(4px);
                filter:blur(4px);
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                background:rgba(255,255,255, 0.9);
                z-index: 2;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            #text{
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                font-size: 50px;
                color: white;
                transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
                -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="overlay" onclick="off()">
            <div id="text">Overlay Text</div>
        </div>

        <body onload="on()">

sguhdulfghldusfhgsdufg

        </body>


        <script>
            function on() {
                document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
            }

            function off() {
                document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What has this to do with PHP?

Comment: Sorry html and css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you just need to change the color of the overlay text to make it visible. But then you have the problem that `blur` will also apply to your child elements and the text is not readable.

In order to make it work you need to create a child element which holds the `blur` to make sure it does not apply to the overlay text.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            #overlay {
                position: fixed;
                display: none;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                background:rgba(255,255,255, 0.9);
                z-index: 2;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            
            #blur {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                -webkit-filter:blur(4px);
                filter:blur(4px);
            }

            #text{
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                font-size: 50px;
                transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
                -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="overlay" onclick="off()">
            <div id="background"></div>
            <div id="text">Overlay Text</div>
        </div>

        <body onload="on()">

sguhdulfghldusfhgsdufg

        </body>


        <script>
            function on() {
                document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
            }

            function off() {
                document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @M.Max is this what you were looking for?